# Having background in the center without having it cut off

Tags: html, css

I needed to center my background image in the exact center of my screen but the current code I have has it such that the image truncated at its top. Here's the code I have so far:

```
body {
    background-image: url(img/tooslow.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
img {
position: absolute;
bottom: 15%;
left: 42.5%;
margin: auto;
width: 250px;
height: 250px;



<a href="tooslow2.html"><img src="img/too1.png"></a>
```

Comment: are you talking about the background image of the `body`element or about the image you have in an `img` tag whose CSS you posted above?

Answer (score 0):

try below updated snippet.

```css
body {
    background-image: url(img/tooslow.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -125px;
    margin-left: -125px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<a href="tooslow2.html"><img src="img/too1.png"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
    background-image: url(http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/Simplest-Responsive-jQuery-Image-Lightbox-Plugin-simple-lightbox.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
img {
position: relative;
bottom: 15%;
left: 42.5%;
margin: auto;
width: 250px;
height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/Simplest-Responsive-jQuery-Image-Lightbox-Plugin-simple-lightbox.jpg"><img src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/Simplest-Responsive-jQuery-Image-Lightbox-Plugin-simple-lightbox.jpg"></a>
```

change your image position to relative

Answer (score 0):

Add below code to img

```
img {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
```